# VM:Allocation causes app to crash

Tags: ios, swift, allocation

My app uses NSTimer variable which uses NSNotificationCenter.postNotificationName to post notification to UIViewController class every seconds.

The issue is the app crashes once in a while with no stacktrace which mean it is a memory issue.

From Instruments, it happens because a 1.78MB increase in VM:Allocation. The allocation just happens randomly.

Here is right after I start the timer:
[image]

Here is when I start the timer for a few minutes
[image]
So,

1. I don't see stacktrace or anything. How do I go about debugging
   this?
2. The app use only 7.3MB and is in the foreground, why does it get
   kill?? :(
3. I just leave the timer running, the method only updating existing
   variables, what trigger this VM:Allocation???

I use Swift, if that matters

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out the problem is in the `for` loop. I had a big `for` loop that do a lot of assignment, calling API, etc, every time the `NSTimer` function is called so sometime when the number of iterations are a little bit too high the VM Allocation kicks in.

The answer I believe is to use `autoreleasepool {}` inside the `for` loop. No crash has happens ever since.
Watching these WWDC2013 video helps a bit in term of ideas but not directly.

[Improving Your App with Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#418)

[Intermediate Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#403)